# flagging all rows relevant rows in Tableau

Tags: loops, tableau-api

I have a source table that has two columns, namely "Record" & "date of change".  For each record type, there can be upto 7 dates of changes, so the record will be repeated 7 times; such as:

Record  Dat_of_change

R1  Jan-19

R1  Feb-19

R1  Jul-19

R1  Dec-19

R2  Jun-20

R2  Jul-20

R3  May-19

R4  Dec-19

R4  Feb-20

R4  May-20

R4  Oct-20

R5  Dec-20

Given a month of interest, I want all rows when a record changed ownership.  For example, if I select  "December 2019" (which I can do using a parameter), then I want all rows for R1 and R4 flagged (via a column that I call "flag" where flag = 1 or 0). In this case, ALL rows for record R1 and R4 will be flagged, not just those where  date is Dec-19.

Any ideas??

Comment: Use `Index()` as your calculated field then adding table calculation on 'compute using' `dat_of_change` may help.

Comment: I got my solution from another source...
{fixed[record]:sum(iif(flag=1,1,0))}>0}

Comment: I would like to see its screenshot.  There are two curly brackets closing while only one has opened?

Comment: hi @AnilGoyal, you are correct, the last } should not be there....it should be:

{fixed [record]:sum(iif([date_of_change]=[parameter],1,0))}>0